# How to replace mutiple similiar values with new value in json using karate

Tags: karate

How to replace mutiple similar values with new value in json using karate.

Here i want to replace false with 0 and N/A with '' in all places in json where ever they present

network": {

```
        "x_forwarded": "N/A",
        "latitude": -1,
        "org": "N/A"
        "data_carrier": false,
        "latitude": -1,
        "sms stealers": "N/A",
        "wifi_security": "N/A",
        "wifi_security1": -1,
        "device_type": "N/A"
        "navigation_props": -1,
        "accept_encoding": "N/A",
        "accept":"N/A",
        "browser_version": "N/A",
        "risky_connection": false,
         "new_location": false,
         "reason": "23",
         "reason_id": -1
         "contact_lastname": "N/A",
         "contact_firstname": "N/A"
```

}